# Boxplot of kmean cluster

Tags: r, visualization

```
 gene   H4       H3       H2       H1       L8       L7       L6       L5       L4       L3       L2       L1          clust
AAGAB  7.540712 7.296325 7.030218 7.408974 8.269541 7.758752 9.253013 8.611002 8.705045 8.940146 8.855133 8.488776     3
ABCA1  7.112951 6.213973 7.200973 6.784828 8.044299 9.832347 8.558342 7.134570 8.993938 5.794208 8.271960 9.179501     5
ABCA6  1.822567 2.209167 3.379618 2.813433 3.180290 3.741516 3.060194 2.078485 6.536346 6.881403 5.927874 5.278854     2
```

This is my output after doing kmean clustering so at the end I have my cluster number assigned to each gene. Now I want to show how the expression of my sample varies across each cluster, I am not sure how to transform the data and do it in `ggplot2` as of now i doing something like this in base R plot

```
boxplot(da$H4 ~ k$cluster, 
        xlab='Cluster', ylab='Genes', 
        main=' Genes by Cluster')
```

For each sample I am checking, is there any way to show that with all the samples together, any suggestion or help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `da` is a data-frame with the cluster as factor you can do the following:

```
ggplot(da) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(cluster, H4)) +
  xlab("Cluster") +
  ylab("Genes") +
  ggtitle("Genes by Cluster")
```

Comment: okay i did something similar  made factor of the clust column then melt  using  melt(da, id.vars=c("clust")) the plot , I got all the cluster expression together..